# Preview issue with var initialized from environment variable

Tags: swiftui

I'm having an issue in preview mode only because of the way I initialise one of my variables.
This view takes a *PlayerScore* as parameter because I need to know which score to edit.
It also has the *game* enviroment object where all scores are stored.

What I do is simple, I search the index of the *playerscore* in the game array of *PlayerScores* in order to later modify it.

Problem with preview is that the PlayerScore I use in the ScoreEntry_Previews is obviously not matching the UUID of the playerScore in the game array. So it won't render the preview because the var initialisation fails as it doesn't find the UUID.

How do I deal with that ?

```
struct ScoreEntry: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var game : Game

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var playerScore: PlayerScore

    var scoreIndex: Int {
        game.playerScores.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == playerScore.id})!
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(self.game.playerScores[self.scoreIndex].totalScore())")
        }
    }
}


struct ScoreEntry_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScoreEntry(
            isPresented: .constant(true)
            ,playerScore: PlayerScore(player: Player(name: "SomePlayer", shortName: "Steph", photoURL:"steph", color: .orange),pointsList: [1,2])
        ).environmentObject(Game())
    }
}
```

```
struct PlayerScore: Identifiable, Hashable {

    var id = UUID()
    let player: Player
    var pointsList: [Int]     

    func totalScore() -> Int {
        return pointsList.reduce(0, +)
    }

    mutating func addPoints(scoreValue: Int) {
        pointsList.append(scoreValue)
    }
}
```

```
class Game: ObservableObject {

    var players = [Player] ()
    @Published var playerScores = [PlayerScore] ()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't auto-generate `id` internally, instead make it injectable, so you can create one in Preview and inject same in both places

```
struct PlayerScore: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID     // << require external
```

**Update:** actually the above is still be possible approach, but below is alternate approach w/o changes in UUID.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Full tested module code

```
struct Player {
    var name: String
    var shortName: String
    var photoURL: String
    var color: Color
}

struct PlayerScore: Identifiable {

    var id = UUID()
    let player: Player
    var pointsList: [Int]

    func totalScore() -> Int {
        return pointsList.reduce(0, +)
    }

    mutating func addPoints(scoreValue: Int) {
        pointsList.append(scoreValue)
    }
}

class Game: ObservableObject {

    var players: [Player]
    @Published var playerScores: [PlayerScore]
    init(players: [Player] = [], scores: [PlayerScore] = []) {
        self.players = players
        self.playerScores = scores
    }
}

struct ScoreEntry: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var game : Game

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var playerScore: PlayerScore

    var scoreIndex: Int {
        game.playerScores.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == playerScore.id})!
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(self.game.playerScores[self.scoreIndex].totalScore())")
        }
    }
}


struct ScoreEntry_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let score = PlayerScore(player: Player(name: "SomePlayer", shortName: "Steph", photoURL:"steph", color: .orange), pointsList: [1, 2])
        return ScoreEntry(isPresented: .constant(true), playerScore: score)
            .environmentObject(Game(scores: [score]))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this approach. When I dont auto-generate id and rather initialise it with a parameter when creating the struct, the preview fails. I use UUID(uuidString: "123") to create the same UUID in the game struct and in the previews

Comment: @GrandSteph, what kind of trouble? Actually it does not matter what the exact value of UUID used, just provide equal one in both places.

Comment: Preview fails. That's all. I switch back to optional or aut-gnerated and previews works. It's the weirdest thing. I found a workaround but it's a bad hack and will bite me in the as... later I"m sure :)

Comment: Ok, I understand why preview was failing. It's irrelevant here. But I need your help because I also finally trully understood your answer. Problem is, I don't see how I can create a UUID in preview and inject it in the game environment object ? @Asperi

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. Really appreciate the help. Works like a charm and I understand now how to inject.